# Add Admin Access to All Accounts

Tags: php, mysql

I am wondering how to get this to work or if it is possible. I have an application that was not built with the admin having access to all the users account but now i want it to have access to all accounts.

Thanks. (though i've not tried anything yet, just dont know how to start and i dont want to start afresh: advice)

My current login code is:

```
        if(isset($_POST['login'])){

        $username = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
        $password = stripslashes($_POST['password']);


        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT password FROM tablename WHERE username=:username");
        $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount()<1){

        echo '<div class="signals"><p class="bg-warning text-center warning"><button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD</div></p>';

        }else{

        list($hash) = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
        //$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        $status1 = "COMPLETED";
        $status2 = "PROCESSING";

        //$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT status FROM ca_confirmed WHERE username ='$_SESSION[username]'");
        $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT status FROM tablename WHERE username ='$username'");
        $check = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $status = $check['status'];

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        if(strcmp($status, $status1) == 0){

        header("location: completed/index.php");
        exit();
        }elseif(strcmp($status, $status2) == 0){

        header("location: uncompleted/index.php");    
        //exit();
        }
        }else{

        echo '<div class="signals"><p class="bg-warning text-center warning"><button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD again</div></p>';

        }    
        }
        }
```

Comment: And what does or doesn't it do?

Comment: Where does the code determine whether the user has access to the account? How do you determine if a user is an admin?

Comment: **Sidenote:** You may find that indenting your code will not only help you, but help those you want help from reading your code much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user logs in, check whether they're an admin, and if so, set a session variable like:

```
$admin = $row['admin'];
$_SESSION['admin'] = $admin;
```

Then your later code can check one of these variables; if it's true, then skip the check for whether the account belongs to the logged in user.

Comment: @OP, just note that if you copy and paste this code, EVERYONE will be "admin". --- Nevermind, Barmar updated his code.

Comment: @BlahArgh I said to do that after first checking whether they're an admin, not unconditionally. But I've clarified it a bit.

Comment: that's why I said "if [he] copy and paste this code", which unfortunately many do without understanding the code first.